# An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run this schematic for my angular project:

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name data-table
```

However, running it in the terminal for vs code gives an error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.
```

Could someone please tell me how I would get rid of this error so that I can generate my required schematic in my angular project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `Angular Material` is broken, try reinstalling using the command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Comment: So after using this command, then I should be able to run ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name data-table successfully?

Comment: Yeah, most probably. If you want to create a mat-table, you can add one in html.

Comment: @Diamoniner12345 - yes.